# It's possible to change the order of bootstrap col div in responsive?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 `col-md-4(1)` `col-md-4(2)` `col-md-4(3)` in `col-md-12`. In mobile or tablet. I want to show middle `col-md-4(2)` first and  then `col-md-4(1)` `col-md-4(3)`. How to do this properly with respect to bootstrap?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <p>abcd</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>xyzs</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>mnop</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The more useful for you is to read the doc : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reorder the first two columns and use `col-xx-push` and `col-xx-pull` to reposition on larger screens:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
        <p>Column 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
        <p>Column 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Column 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can not use `push` and `pull` when your columns are full width (in your case, below `md`) so you must have them in the correct order in the DOM to start with.

Comment: great..Thanks for help..!